# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  select to_char(r.rut_cli,'99G999G999')||'-'|| r.dv_cli RUT_CLIENTE ,
    to_char(ROUND(r.monto_compras),'$999,999,999,999') AS "MontoComprasRegistrado"
     , to_char(ROUND(sum(s.total_sali)),'$999,999,999') AS "MontoComprasCalculado"
     , to_char(ROUND(sum(s.total_sali) - r.monto_compras),'$999,999,999,999') AS "Dif.MontoCalculado|Registrado"
  from resumen_vta_cliente r join det_despacho d on r.rut_cli=d.rut_cli
       join salida s on d.cod_sali=s.cod_sali
       join det_salida z on (s.cod_sali=z.cod_sali)
 where d.estado_des='E'
   and z.cod_prod = (select cod_prod from producto where cod_tipo ='&CODIGO_TIPO') 
   and s.estado_sali='V'
 group by  r.rut_cli, r.dv_cli
 having r.monto_compras > (select min(total_sali) from salida)
 order by r.rut_cli,r.dv_cli;
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>         Error en la línea: 26, columna: 9

Line 26 is `having r.monto_compras > (select min(total_sali) from salida)`

Comment: So why have you tagged MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: `r.monto_compras` is not in an aggregation function and is not in the `group by` clause

Comment: what it does mean? Because even if i add r.monto_compras in the group by clause i keep getting the same error in the same line 26...

Comment: Just google the error and you would understand what it means. Also when you say `even if i add r.monto_compras in the group by clause`, that means you don't understand the data set or expected output correctly. So provide table structure, sample data, and expected output for the sample data. If possible create a sample table in [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) so others can see the problem for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from remove `r.monto_compras` in your sql, this will work.

```
 select to_char(r.rut_cli,'99G999G999')||'-'|| r.dv_cli RUT_CLIENTE ,
--    to_char(ROUND(r.monto_compras),'$999,999,999,999') AS "MontoComprasRegistrado"
     , to_char(ROUND(sum(s.total_sali)),'$999,999,999') AS "MontoComprasCalculado"
--     , to_char(ROUND(sum(s.total_sali) - r.monto_compras),'$999,999,999,999') AS "Dif.MontoCalculado|Registrado"
  from resumen_vta_cliente r join det_despacho d on r.rut_cli=d.rut_cli
       join salida s on d.cod_sali=s.cod_sali
       join det_salida z on (s.cod_sali=z.cod_sali)
 where d.estado_des='E'
   and z.cod_prod = (select cod_prod from producto where cod_tipo ='&CODIGO_TIPO') 
   and s.estado_sali='V'
 group by  r.rut_cli, r.dv_cli
 -- having r.monto_compras > (select min(total_sali) from salida)
 order by r.rut_cli,r.dv_cli;
```

You may get result from it.
And now, remove comment and then add `r.monto_compras` to group by clause.

```
group by  r.rut_cli, r.dv_cli, r.monto_compras
having r.monto_compras > (select min(total_sali) from salida)
```

But I'm not sure work or not, I don't have any script for this.
If you have table script, we need it to solve your problem as soon as possible.

Here is what I've tested.(Note: I tested this on PostgreSQL + Oracle)

```
create table resumen_vta_cliente( 
    rut_cli integer,
    dv_cli varchar(10),
    monto_compras integer 
);

create table det_despacho( 
    rut_cli integer,
    cod_sali integer,
    estado_des varchar(10) 
);

create table salida( 
    cod_sali integer,
    estado_sali varchar(10),
    total_sali integer 
);


create table det_salida( 
    cod_sali integer,
    estado_sali varchar(10),
    cod_prod varchar(10) 
);

create table producto( 
    cod_prod varchar(10),
    cod_tipo varchar(10) 
);
```